# Modify column records based on values in a different table

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to modify records in a column of one table whenever I meet some condition in another table.

Specifically, whenever there is a 'y' in the RobotComRein.Reinforcement table/column, I want to add a 1 to the table/column: RobotComYN.Yesses.

Furthermore, both tables have columns called "RobotID" and "Command" and I would like to make the change only when the following condition is met:

RobotComRein.RobotID = RobotComYN.RobotID 
AND RobotComRein.Command = RobotComYN.Command

I have tried messing around with the following SQL statement.

```
UPDATE RobotComYN
SET Yesses = Yesses + 1
WHERE RobotComRein.Reinforcement IN (
    SELECT RobotComRein.Reinforcement
    FROM RobotComRein
    WHERE RobotComRein.Reinforcement = 'y' 
    AND RobotComRein.RobotID = RobotComYN.RobotID 
    AND RobotComRein.Command = RobotComYN.Command
);
```

I receive the following error message:
"no such column: RobotComRein.Reinforcement"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about context and the order that tables are referenced. You are trying to reference another table from the UPDATE's WHERE clause, but there is no relationship between the two tables at that level. It is okay to reference the "outer" table from the nested query inside the parenthesis, but not vice versa. In other words, you are updating `RobotComYN`, so you can't directly reference `RobotComRein` table columns in the WHERE clause.

See [How to UPDATE a SQLITE Column with an INNER JOIN on TWO FIELDS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175803/how-to-update-a-sqlite-column-with-an-inner-join-on-two-fields/175813).  The following are customized statements based on the accepted answer:

```
UPDATE RobotComYN
SET Yesses = Yesses + 1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT RobotComRein.RobotID 
              FROM RobotComRein
              WHERE (RobotComRein.RobotID = RobotComYN.RobotID)
                AND (RobotComRein.Command = RobotComYN.Command)
                AND RobotComRein.Reinforcement = 'y'
             );
```

Notice that the inner select of the original answer was `SELECT *`, but it is unnecessary to return all columns just to test for existence of a matching row.  Only a single column is needed and is more efficient.

```
UPDATE RobotComYN
SET Yesses = Yesses + 1
WHERE (RobotID, Command) IN (
    SELECT RobotComRein.RobotID, RobotComRein.Command 
    FROM RobotComRein
    WHERE RobotComRein.Reinforcement = 'y');
```

---

The following update sets the new value from an *aggregate* query that counts the rows of the related table:

```
UPDATE RobotComYN
SET Yesses = Yesses + (
    SELECT Count(RobotComRein.RobotID) AS increase
    FROM RobotComRein
    WHERE RobotComRein.RobotID = RobotComYN.RobotID
          AND RobotComRein.Command = RobotComYN.Command
          AND RobotComRein.Reinforcement = 'y')
WHERE (RobotID, Command) IN (
    SELECT RobotComRein.RobotID, RobotComRein.Command 
    FROM RobotComRein
    WHERE RobotComRein.Reinforcement = 'y');
```

I was originally thinking that a WITH statement would eliminate the need for multiple subqueries, but that flawed thinking eventually gets back to the fact that the sqlite UPDATE statement does not support direct joins on the updated table.  The WITH statement still does not eliminate the need to redefine the "join" columns for both sub-queries--it does not simplify the query.  About the only benefit to the WITH statement is that the WITH query will be executed only once which applies any filters and aggregates.

```
WITH filtered AS (
     SELECT RobotID, Command, Count(*) AS increase
        FROM RobotComRein
        WHERE RobotComRein.Reinforcement = 'y'
        GROUP BY RobotID, Command)
UPDATE RobotComYN
SET Yesses = Yesses + (
    SELECT increase
    FROM filtered
    WHERE filtered.RobotID = RobotComYN.RobotID
          AND filtered.Command = RobotComYN.Command)
WHERE (RobotID, Command) IN (
    SELECT filtered.RobotID, filtered.Command 
    FROM filtered);
```

Comment: Thank you!  Now I'm confused since the query seems to only add one to the "Yesses" column.  Sometimes there are more than one yesses to add for a specific RobotID/Command pair.  How would I go about iterating through and adding as many as are detected with the same RobotID/Command?

Comment: The idea of "iteration" over the rows of a relational database is not preferred.  Instead, the idea is to operate on a set of data, often without the concept of a row-by-row operation in a particular order.  The lines can be blurred a bit and technically there must be some kind of iteration by the database engine, but a different mindset can be useful.  With an sqlite UPDATE statement, you'll need to set the WHERE clause and the SET clause separately. I can show details later, but a hint would be to use WITH statement to reuse a subquery which counts the number of matches in the related table.